# LUIS V2 Datetime Resolution Not Reachable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I converted my LUIS entities from datetime to datetimeV2 & am running Bot.Builder 3.11.0 . In code, the following line extracts an `EntityRecommendation`

```
result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetimeV2.date", out startDate)
```

The resulting object doesn't allow me to reach the "timex" value at all. How do I access the resolutions? by the time I try to access "timex" it says cant use []  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bit verbose but it's doable. You need to do:

```
if (result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetimeV2.date", out EntityRecommendation dateEntity))
{
    var resolutionValues = (IList<object>)dateEntity.Resolution["values"];

    var values = (IDictionary<string, object>)resolutionValues[0];

    await context.PostAsync($"Timex: {values["timex"]}");
    await context.PostAsync($"Type: {values["type"]}");
    await context.PostAsync($"Value: {values["value"]}");
}
```

I created a set of extensions method that you might find useful. Check https://github.com/ejadib/LUIS-DateTimeV2-Extensions